How to relate a sequence following an error fuction and another sequence derived from the first sequence using their standard deviations?
I am an engineering student and want to derive a reasonable relation between a sequence derived from a normal distribution and the other seqence derived from the first sequence.
I have a sequence of monotonically increasing real numbers $d_i$, $i \in [1, N]$ from a negative value to a positive value (for example, $d_1 = -2$ and $d_N = 2$). For this sequence, I apply the error function of a normal distribution $\mathcal{N} \left( 0, \sigma \right)$ to get \begin{eqnarray}
    \alpha_{i,\sigma} = \frac{1}{2} + \text{erf} \left( \frac{-d_i}{\sqrt{2 \sigma^{2}}} \right).
\end{eqnarray}
Now, I get another sequence
\begin{eqnarray}
    \beta_{i,\sigma} = \text{exclusive_cumprod} \left( 1 - \alpha_{i,\sigma} \right) \alpha_{i,\sigma}
\end{eqnarray}
where $\text{exclusive_cumprod} \left( c_i \right) = \Pi_{j=1}^{i-1} c_{i} ~ \text{if} ~ i = 1 ~ \text{otherwise} ~ 1$.
As you may notice, $\beta_{i,\sigma}$ behaves like a Probability Density Function (PDF), and its cumulative summation acts as a Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF). Assuming the resultant CDF also follows a normal distribution, $\beta_{i,\sigma} \approx \mathcal{N} \left( 0, \sigma^{\prime} \right)$, I want to find a relation between $\sigma$ and $\sigma^{\prime}$ (ideally, a relation showing $\sigma$ acts as an upper bound of $\sigma^{\prime}, $ $\sigma^{\prime} < \sigma$). But, I have not come up with a clue as to how to find the relation. Does anybody suggest how to derive it or recommend materials for a solution? I confirmed the relation holds numerically under certain setups. I am seeking a theoretical endorsement.
Thanks in advance!
